# How to use Adaptive Cards for Teams Unfurling in botbuilder JS?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

How to use adaptive cards for unfurling ?

I am able to send heroCard or thumbnailCard.
Now trying something like this, but it doesn't work for me.

```
handleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery(context: TurnContext, query: AppBasedLinkQuery) {
    const attachment = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "body": [...],
        "actions": [...],
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.2"
    });

    const result = {
        attachmentLayout: 'list',
        type: 'result',
        attachments: [attachment]
    };

    return {
        composeExtension: result
    };
}
```

Documentation says it is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=javascript

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!
If you want to use Adaptive cards, they should have a preview.

So instead of:

```
const attachment = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(...)
```

You can write something like this and it works perfect:

```
const attachment = {
    ...CardFactory.adaptiveCard(...),
    preview: CardFactory.heroCard(..., ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not really a solution as it just shows the hero card and not the adaptive card. Showing the adaptive card in the link unfurling chat window appears not to work.

Comment: if you press "expand", it will show the adaptive card

Comment: poor UX. trying to match customer UX in Slack.... pressing expand is an extra step that the business doesn't want.